# Sequential numbering of records...Specific Record IDs

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite DB with a date field like this:

- 2011/06/15

  2012/03/23

  2013/03/23

what I want to do is remove the slashes (simple and I've done it) but I want make the date with a sequential numbering for each year like this:

- - 20110615.0001

    20110615.0002

    20120615.0001

    20120615.0002

    20120615.0003

    20130615.0001

    20130615.0002

    20140615.0001

It counts each year in a separate sequential manner, I have years from 1998 to 2014 with thaw thousands of records for each one

To clarify things more, I have about 2 million records stored in sqlite DB and there is a date for each record, want to use that date for giving each record a unique ID like the above example, the day or the month are not important but I want to use the year as base for the ID 2011****.0001 , 2011****.0002 and count from 0001 to whatever number for this year and for another year start counting again...I hope I made it clear

thanks
ibrahim

Comment: What is the input data for which these values would be the desired output?

Comment: it is a file numbering system and it should be like that

Comment: What is the *specific* example input that should generate this output?

Comment: 2011/06/15...the dates itself different days for each year and I want to make it like this 20110615.0001 remove the slashes and add a numbering for each year regardless the date

Comment: To clarify things more, I have about 2 million records stored in sqlite DB and there is a date for each record, want to use that date for giving each record a unique ID like the above example, the day or the month are not important but I want to use the year as base for the ID 2011****.0001 , 2011****.0002 and count from 0001 to whatever number for this year and for another year start counting again...I hope I made it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the date values are already in the `yyyymmdd` format, you can just count how many previous rows with the same year there are:

```
UPDATE MyTable
Set MyDate = MyDate ||
             printf('.%04d', (SELECT COUNT(*)
                              FROM MyTable AS T2
                              WHERE substr(T2.MyDate,      1, 4) =
                                    substr(MyTable.MyDate, 1, 4)
                                AND T2.MyDate <= MyTable.MyDate))
```

If there are duplicate dates, you must use some other unique column:

```
UPDATE MyTable
Set MyDate = MyDate ||
             printf('.%04d', (SELECT COUNT(*)
                              FROM MyTable AS T2
                              WHERE substr(T2.MyDate,      1, 4) =
                                    substr(MyTable.MyDate, 1, 4)
                                AND T2.rowid <= MyTable.rowid))
```

Comment: Thank you very much...I'll let you know how it goes. Apologies for the delay.